# Why is Amy Chua's book called "Battle Hymn of the Tiger Mother" instead of "Battle Hymn of the Mother-Tigress"?

Tags: title, battle-hymn-of-the-tiger-mother, amy-chua

In my language, the title of *Battle Hymn of the Tiger Mother* has been translated as *Боевой гимн матери-тигрицы*, which translates to "Battle hymn of the mother-tigress". I think Ms Chua meant the word "tiger" as a noun, not as an adjective. So, in this case "mother-tigress" would be right. Is this correct?

Comment: Both *tiger mother* and *mother tigress* are perfectly good English phrases that mean essentially the same thing. In the first, *tiger* is an attributive noun (so a noun that behaves a little bit like an adjective) and in the second, *mother* is an attributive noun.

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple reasons: first and foremost, the term “Tiger Mother” was already in common use, particularly among Chinese-Americans to describe the kind of parenting style that Chua writes about in her book.

Second, is that in English, “Tiger Mother” has Tiger modifying mother and describes a mother with the attributes of a tiger (the term is a bit hyperbolic, intentionally so). “Mother Tigress” on the other hand would be a tigress who is a mother, and would be more likely applied to an actual female tiger than a human being.

Comment: Do you have a reference for 'the term “Tiger Mother” was already in common use, particularly among Chinese-Americans'?

Comment: @bobble https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/12/tiger-mother.html addresses this.